# react-native multi select change select text color

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native and i am trying to add multi selection component to my app
my code is as follows:

```
   <SectionedMultiSelect
              items={this.state.days}
              uniqueKey="id"
              hideSearch={true}
              subKey="day"
              selectText="Select Days"
              selectToggle={{ color: '#f79334' }}
              showDropDowns={true}
              readOnlyHeadings={true}
              onSelectedItemsChange={this.onSelectedItemsChangeHomeRepair}
              selectedItems={this.state.selectedDaysHomeRepair}
              showChips={false}
              theme = {
                {
                  Colors:{ 
                    selectToggleTextColor:'#053075',
                    text:'#053075'
                   }
                }
              }
            />
```

does anyone know how to apply color to "Select Days" text. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `renderSelectText` prop and pass your own text component with your custom styles.

```
<SectionedMultiSelect
  items={this.state.days}
  uniqueKey="id"
  hideSearch={true}
  subKey="day"
  renderSelectText={() => <Text style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: 24 }}>Select Days</Text>}
  selectToggle={{ color: '#f79334' }}
  showDropDowns={true}
  readOnlyHeadings={true}
  onSelectedItemsChange={this.onSelectedItemsChangeHomeRepair}
  selectedItems={this.state.selectedDaysHomeRepair}
  showChips={false}
  theme = {
    {
      Colors: { 
        selectToggleTextColor:'#053075',
        text:'#053075'
      }
    }
  }
/>
```

Have a look at how this can be used in the example [here](https://github.com/renrizzolo/react-native-sectioned-multi-select/blob/45e68a7ea92345c19c34cd7a464c14d1e4392657/exampleapp/App.js#L548).

Comment: its working, I want to change toggle icon color also, is there any way to do this?, please help

Comment: Which toggle are you referring to? Could you please provide a full working example?

Comment: This.component has its built in toggle icon, Thank you by the way, i did it using colors object pass as props to the component as per their docuementation.